# how to refer to the loop value in the loop itself in python panda?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to do do a loop to repeat the following instructions. The loop should consider nivel1, nivel2,nivel3 and nivel4. Is there a smart way to do this? So far I have tried

```
for x in range(2, 5):
    n_index = len(VaR_nivel1.index)
    n_columns = len(VaR_nivel1.columns)
    VaR_profit_nivel1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(n_index ,n_columns ))
    VaR_profit_nivel1.columns = VaR_nivel1.columns
    zero_one_nivel1= pd.DataFrame(np.zeros ((n_index, n_columns)))
    columna=0
    indices=0
    while indices<n_index:
        while columna< n_columns:
            VaR_profit_nivel1.iloc[indices,columna]=VaR_nivel1.iloc[indices,columna] + profit_nivel1.iloc[indices,columna] 
            if VaR_profit_nivel1.iloc[indices,columna] <0:
                zero_one_nivel1.iloc[indices,columna]=1    
            columna += 1
        indices += 1
```

And then I have to change the level1 for something like levelx...
Thank you.

Comment: those while-loops should probably be for-loops. Although, if you are working with pandas/numpy, you might not need any loops.  Please provide a [mcve], and a description of what you are trying to accomplish. Example input/ouput is always very helpful

Comment: What I want to do is to find a way to use a for loop in order not to repeat my code 4 times and making some minor changes, for example changing VaR_nivel1 for VaR_nivel2 and so on...

Comment: that is not a [mcve]